# JTable TableRowSorter or Re-query MySQL DB?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jtable

Using JDBC and MySQL I am displaying a MySQL table in a JTable.
Currently as soon as my Java application is launched the Database table is being queried for all results (e.g. SELECT * FROM tableExample) which then get displayed by the JTable.

My question is, if I wish to apply a filter (or two) is it better to re-query the MySQL table and update the JTable or is it better to use the TableRowSorter()?

Currently my table contains ~23,000 results.

Also if anyone has advise or code example of how to update a JTable from a new query I would very much appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every JTable has a TableModel that holds it's data. The default implementation is DefaultTableModel, but you can implement your own, depending on the filters you want to use. If you query the database again, you can set the data on the TableModel or set a new instance of a TableModel on the JTable.

```
model = new DefaultTableModel();
table = new JTable(model);

...query the database, do either:
model.setDataVector(...);
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(...));
```

The question, whether it is better to query the database or to do client filtering/sorting can not be answered universally. It depends on your environment and your use case. If you query from a remote database, it might be better to do client filtering because transmitting 23k rows of data would take to long. If your client is a rather slow machine, sorting in the database could be faster than doing it in Java. If these kind of resources are not the problem, use what ever solution you are more comfortable with. Sorting in Java is a little bit more work than in SQL, on the other hand filtering is more versatile when implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1):

there are lots of workaround for your question for example [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) or [ResultSet Table](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ResultSetTable.htm)

search in this forum too,

search on google with ResultSetTableModel,

its hart to tell which workaround is better,

but `Currently my table contains ~23,000 results.` for that would be better to reduce number of Rows in SQL statement,